# Is it possible to read Relax NG xml in  XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, relaxng

I want to know whether it is possible to transform Relax NG XML with XSLT. Please give me some tutorial.

I don't seem to be able to match the grammar-tag in the RelaxNG schema below with `<xsl:template match="grammar">`

```
<grammar>

  <start>
    <element name="html">
      <zeroOrMore>
        <ref name="section"/>
      </zeroOrMore>
    </element>
  </start>

  <define name="section">
    <element name="div">
      <attribute name="class"><value>section</value></attribute>
      <zeroOrMore>
        <element name="para">
          <text/>
        </element>
      </zeroOrMore>
      <zeroOrMore>
        <ref name="subsection"/>
      </zeroOrMore>
   </element>
  </define>



</grammar>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relax NG is a language for expressing a grammar of XML. W3C XML Schema is also such a language. XSLT however, is a language of transforming XML into another data format. In other words, they cover different grounds. Do you really mean to convert Relax NG into XSLT?

You find quite some XSLT's that you can use to optimize, transform etc your Relax NG, DTD or XML Schema to / from each other on the [Relax NG homepage](http://relaxng.org/).

Just guessing: you might actually be after is a tool to validate existing XML by its Relax NG schema. You can do that with [any one of the validators](http://relaxng.org/#validators).

EDIT, based on your last comment. The reason that your `xsl:template` isn't hit is most likely because you didn't specify the RelaxNG namespace. You didn't show any of your code, but try to apply something like the following to your stylesheet (note that the namespace prefix doesn't matter and doesn't need to be in the source XML document):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:ng="http://relaxng.org/ns/structure/1.0">

    <xsl:template match="ng:grammar">
        <xsl:text>Grammar found!</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user1283110 _"Is type of syntax is possible to read in xslt provide me some sample i am new to this "_ >> you can read / transform any XML with XSLT. Relax NG _is_ XML, so you can read it with XSLT. But you cannot convert Relax NG to XSLT, because they're different beasts entirely (one is for validation, other for transformation). It _is_ technically possible to write a validator in XSLT, but if one exists I don't know. There are many validators around, so I don't see the need.

Comment: @ Abel But i did not get the grammer tag in xslt  <xsl:template match ="grammer "> </xsl:template> in grammer tag having some name space so it is not matching

Comment: @user1283110: now we're getting somewhere. So your question is actually "how to process RelaxNG in XSLT, I can't seem to match the grammar-element". See my edit.

Comment: Ya correct This is my question (how to process RelaxNG in XSLT)

Comment: @ Abel I have One define name="Clinical_information" inside that i am having many element eg i have having 5 elements but i having some child as choice, option is it possible to apply for each  loop

Comment: @user1283110: anything is possible, but I haven't seen any code of you so it's hard to comment. May I suggest you ask an XSLT-question about the specifics that you have problems with? Make sure to post the failing code parts and make the parts as small as possible. to illustrate your issue. There are many XSLT specialists at StackOverflow.

Comment: @ Abel ok thanks for support Above code is working fine Again thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean, can I compile a Relax NG schema into an XSLT stylesheet that performs the validation implied by the schema?

The answer is, yes, theoretically you can, if you have a good understanding of the computer science theory of (a) how to convert a BNF grammar to a finite state automaton, and (b) how to implement a finite state automaton in a functional programming language.

Somehow, though, I suspect that if this is what you wanted to do then you wouldn't have asked the question in the way you did.